# Complex Numbers and the Triangle Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, quadratics

I'm working on the following problem for my introductory complex variables course.

> By factoring $z^4-4z^2+3$ in two quadratic factors and using inequality derived from the triangle inequality, show that if $z$ lies on the circle $|z|=2$, then $$ 
> \bigg|\frac{1}{z^4-4z^2+3}\bigg| \ge\frac{1}{19} $$

I'm not really sure how to attack this problem, I've tried multiple methods but can't seem to get anywhere with them. My first attempt was factoring $z^4-4z^2+3$ into $z^2(z+2)(z-2)+3$ to try and use it with the triangle inequality, but am not really sure how to implement this into the triangle inequality.

A general hint towards solving problems similar to this will suffice. I'm not looking for an exact answer, but any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The statement is false. Take $z=-2$. Then $\left|\frac1{z^4-4z^3+3}\right|=\frac1{51}<\frac1{19}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's my fault. I made a mistake. The correct statement should be $z^4-4z^2+3$. I fixed it.

Comment: Quadratic factors have the form $(az^2+bz+c)$; your factorisation is into a quadratic factor, two linear and a remainder.  If you set $w=z^2$ and consider the denominator now as $w^2-4w+3$ you can probably get the right two factors pretty quickly!

Comment: Ah, now it makes much more sense. Treat it as a quadratic polynomial in $z^2$. You know how to factor those, right?

Comment: Still false. Take $z=\sqrt2+\sqrt2i$. Then $\left|\frac1{z^4-4z^2+3}\right|=\left|-\frac1{13+16i}\right|=\frac1{5\sqrt{17}}<\frac1{19}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, that's what my professor gave me. No restrictions on the domain or anything. He does have a habit of making a lot of mathematical typos, do you believe this is a mistake?

Comment: @Kosta It seems likely.

Comment: Factoring within sums (example $x^2 +4x + 4 = x(x+4) + 4$) almost never reveals anything useful.  And $z^2(z+2)(z-2) + 3$ is not "two quadratic factors". Factor the *whole* thing.  $z^4 -4z + 3= (z^2-1)(z^2-3)$ That's two quadratic factors.

Comment: The right hand side should be $1/35$, assuming the left hand side is correct. That value is achieved at $z=\pm 2i$.

Comment: Yeah... I get easily that $(z^2 - 1) \le |z^2| + 1 = 5$ and $|z^2 -3| \le 7$ so the whole thing is greater than $1/35$ and if $z = 2i$ then equality holds and the whole thing is $1/35 < 1/19$.

Comment: Thank you, I sent my professor an email and will update this forum with a response. I'll work off the $1/35$ assumption and post my solution today. Thank you.

Comment: @Kosta My guess is that the denominator should be $\,z^3-4z+3\,$, instead.

Comment: @dxiv How would we factor $z^3 -4z +3$ into two quadratics?

Comment: @fleablood We don't, and don't have to. Just $|z^3 - 4z+3|\le 2^3+4\cdot 2+3=19\,$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to ask for a proof of the statement $|z|=2\Longrightarrow|z^4-4z^2+3|\leqslant19$?

Comment: @dxiv Ah.  You are probably correct and this is an entire cut and paste error rather than a mere typo: "By *factoring z4−4z2+3 in two quadratic factors* and using inequality derived from the triangle inequality" simply does not apply to the problem $z^3 - 4z + 3$ but the triangle inequality that derives *directly* will give the result with 1/19.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It would be.  But the teacher is being obtuse which... is his perogative, I guess,.... just wish he wouldn't make so many typos.  I mean we are having a *lot* of heartache for very little relevant insight.

Comment: I just got a reply from my professor, the correct RHS is $1/34$

Comment: He said 1/34, but I messaged him back and he meant 1/35. I'm in for one hell of a semester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a typo.

$z^4 - 4z^2 + 3 = (z^2 -1)(z^2 - 3)$.  If $|z| = 2$ then $|z^2| = 4$.

$|z^2 - 1| \le |z^2| + 1 = 5; |z^2 -3| \le |z^2| + 3 = 7$ so

$|z^4 - 4z^2 + 3| = |z^2 -1||z^2 -3|\le 5*7 = 35$

And $|\frac 1 {z^4 - 4z^2 + 3}| \ge \frac 1{35}$

Equality holds if $|z^2 - 1| = |z^2| +1$ and $|z^2 - 3| = |z^2| +3$ which happens if $z^2 = -4$ or if $z = \pm 2i$.

So $|\frac 1 {z^4 - 4z^2 + 3}|_{z = \pm 2i} = \frac 1{35} < \frac 1{19}$

On the other hand if $|z^2| = 4$ then $|z^2 - 1| \ge  |z^2| - 1 = 3$ and $|z^2 - 3| > |z^2| - 3 = 1$ (with equality holding if $z = \pm 2$) and so $ \frac 1{35} \le |\frac 1 {z^4 - 4z^2 + 3}| \le \frac 13$.

Comment: After working through the problem as everyone above suggested, I did get this answer. Thank you.